Editing an RDL File
I’m working on an RDL file and need help duplicating an existing table and linking it to a new value. Currently, the report has a table (table8) that displays Administration Expenses. I want to add a new table directly below it, identical in format, structure, and dataset references, but linked to the value Handling instead of Administration.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:

Duplicate the Existing Table: Copy the structure of the table8 table and place it directly below the original.
Link to "Handling": The new table should reference the value Handling, just as the original table references Administration.

I’ve tried making the changes myself, but I haven’t been able to get the new table to appear correctly in the report. If someone could help by modifying the attached RDL file or guiding me on how to achieve this, I would be incredibly grateful.
Thank you so much for your time and support!
